# doesNotRecognizeSelector exception while running ibtool on a xib resource files

Tags: xcode, ios4, xcode4, ibtool

Anyone knows why I get this crash from the ibtool?

`ibtool --generate-strings-file "my.strings" "myViewController.xib"`

Result:

```
2011-04-18 17:49:41.848 ibtoold[32147:107] -[NSCFString count]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x20055f7e0
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
<key>com.apple.ibtool.errors</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>description</key>
        <string>Exception while running ibtool: -[NSCFString count]:     unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x20055f7e0
Backtrace:
  0  0x00007fff81780796 __exceptionPreprocess (in CoreFoundation)
  1  0x00007fff8300e0f3 objc_exception_throw (in libobjc.A.dylib)
  2  0x00007fff817da110 +[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] (in CoreFoundation)
  3  0x00007fff8175291f ___forwarding___ (in CoreFoundation)
  4  0x00007fff8174ea68 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 (in CoreFoundation)
  5  0x00000001000ea974 IBAppendStringsfileEntries (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
  6  0x00000001000eac4b IBGenerateStringsfile (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be a bug in the new Version of `ibtool`. In my case it was a UISearchBar in which the placeholder text was set.

Even removing the placeholder text does not resolve the issue, since Interface Builder leaves droppings in the `.xib`. Removing the search bar completely and adding a fresh one without setting the placeholder text fixes the exception.

One workaround for this problem: use `$DEVELOPER_DIR/usr/bin/ibtool3` which seems to be the old version of the tool.

Comment: I had the same problem, and recreating UISearchBar without a placeholder solved it. Thank you.